# How do I copy a folder keeping owners and permissions intact?

Tags: permissions, cp

So I was going to back up my home folder by copying it to an external drive as follows:

```
sudo cp -r /home/my_home /media/backup/my_home
```

With the result that all folders on the external drives are now owned by `root:root`. How can I have `cp` keep the ownership and permissions from the original?

Answer (score 684, accepted):

```
sudo cp -rp /home/my_home /media/backup/my_home
```

From cp manpage:

```
 -p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

 --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
          preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps),
          if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

Comment: Much better to use `cp -a`.  This also includes the `-r`ecursive flag, but it does more than that—it preserves everything about the file; SELinux attributes, links, xattr, everything.  It's "archive mode."  There are better tools for making a backup, but *if* you're using `cp` for a backup, don't use anything other than `cp -a`.

Comment: It works, but Patience is Good here. The command will only set everything right when it finishes: While it's still copying a directory, and you're running cp as root, the directory will be owned by root. It will only set it to the right permissions when it finishes with this directory.

Comment: `cp -a` doesn't work on some systems: e.g. OS X, where (in some versions at least) one needed to use `cp -pR`. On my current OS X system though (10.10.15), `cp -a` seems to be honored.

Comment: If I use cp -a to copy a folder structure then use `diff <(getfacl -R folder1) <(getfacl -R folder2)` i sill seem to get different access control lists :(

Comment: why do you right "cp -rp", not " cp -p" ?

Comment: @EugeneKaurov -r is recursive. Without it you can't copy directories.

Comment: AFAIK, do note that this does not preserve `setcap`/`getcap`. I recently had a problem where `ping` would return `operation not permitted`. Now I wonder what other binaries are missing `setcap`.

Comment: @philx_x `sudo` is needed to preserve user ownership, unless you're already the root user. See @telCom's comment.

Comment: Just tested on Ubuntu and that command copies the folder named my_home into /media/backup/my_home which means you end up with  /media/backup/my_home/my_home

Comment: @LoneSpawn only if /media/backup/my_home already exists, it does so of course

Answer (score 130):

You can also use `rsync`.

```
sudo rsync -a /home/my_home/ /media/backup/my_home/
```

From the `rsync` manpage:

```
 -a, --archive
              This  is  equivalent  to  -rlptgoD.  It  is a quick way of saying you want
              recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with -H being a  notable
              omission).    The   only  exception  to  the  above  equivalence  is  when
              --files-from is specified, in which case -r is not implied.

              Note that -a does not preserve hardlinks, because finding  multiply-linked
              files is expensive.  You must separately specify -H.
```

See this question for a comparison between `cp` and `rsync`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6339287/406686

Note the trailing slashes (see manpage for details).

Comment: +1, `cp -p` is nice, but I like `rsync`'s output so much more in general that I've aliased `pcp` to `time rsync --progress -ah`.  Stands for "progress copy" in my mind.  And both accept `-r`, so it works well for general terminal usage - but unfortunately, not in combination with `sudo` as shown in this question/answer.

Comment: NB: `rsync -a`, does not preserve extended attributes (`-X`) and no ACLs (`-A`) - the short description says `archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)`. E.g. SELinux contexts will not be preserverd without `-X`. For many use cases this is fine, but if you make a backup of your system partition, missing -X might break quite a lot. As far as I know, `cp -a` really preserves all file attributes.

Comment: Just tested this, while `sudo cp -a` preserves ownership and groups, `sudo rsync -a` changes them into root. So, @Perseids is correct.

Comment: @JohnHamilton Under Mint, this works perfectly... it only changes ownership and groups later on (I can't tell when). I've just copied my whole `/home` folder with `rsync -aX /home /mnt/sdd/` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @JohnHamilton that's not what Perseides said at all.

Comment: @user643011 I was really referring to this part: "For many use cases this is fine, but if you make a backup of your system partition, missing -X might break quite a lot. As far as I know, cp -a really preserves all file attributes."

Answer (score 94):

```
cp -a
```

Where `-a` is short for `--archive` — basically it copies a directory exactly as it is; the files retain all their attributes, and symlinks are not dereferenced (`-d`).

From `man cp`:

```
   -a, --archive
          same as -dR --preserve=all
```

Comment: Which doesn’t preserve ᴀᴄʟs.

Answer (score 27):

I use `cp -pdRx` which will `-p` preserve mode, ownership & timestamps, `-d` preserve links (so you get symlinks instead the file contents copied), `-R` do it recursively and `-x` stay on one file system (only really useful if you're copying `/` or something with an active mount point).

PS: `-R` instead of `-r` is just habit from using `ls -lR`.

Comment: `cp -ax` is a slightly shorter version of the same thing. This worked great - thank you!

Comment: Actually there is a difference between `-r` and `-R`. Check the man page (even the particular part too long to be quoted here).

Comment: I don't think there is (although there may once have been and may still be on some versions of Unix). See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html It simply says `-R, -r, --recursive      copy directories recursively`.

Comment: Warning regarding `cp -ax`: With `sym-src-dir` being a symlink to `real-src-dir`, when I executed `cp -ax sym-src-dir dest-dir`, all it did was create a symlink `dest-dir` pointing to `real-src-dir`; it **did not copy** anything from inside `real-src-dir/*` to ``dest-dir/`.

Comment: @Abdull - that is expected behavior with the `-a` switch. `-a` infers `-d` (which preserves links as links - rather than following them). If you want to follow all symlinks and include them as files/directories (instead of just symlinks) use `-r --preserve=all`. Please note that as per your example, it will include `real-src-dir` (but dir will be named `sym-src-dir`)

Answer (score 19):

You can do something like this:

```
tar cf - my_home | (cd /media/backup; sudo tar xf - )
```

`tar` keeps permissions, ownership and directory structure intact, but converts everything into a stream of bytes.  You run a "subshell" (the parenthesized commands) that change directory, and then get `tar` to reverse the conversion.  A steam of bytes becomes directories and files with correct ownership and permissions.

Comment: Is there a difference between using `tar` and using `cp -rp` as other answers suggest?

Comment: @lucidbrot - I would think `tar` and `cp -rp` would differ only in corner cases - how they handle symbolic links or other special files, handling extended attributes of some filesystems, or dealing with sparse files.

Comment: +1 This is a very UNIX way of doing this. It also copies symbolic links as symbolic links.

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 16):

`cp` has an option to preserve file ownership. From the manual page of `cp`:

```
-p    Cause cp to preserve the following attributes of each source file in the copy: modification
      time, access time, file flags, file mode, user ID, and group ID, as allowed by permissions.
      Access Control Lists (ACLs) and Extended Attributes (EAs), including resource forks, will also
      be preserved.
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer is simple: `cp` has a `-p` option that preserves permissions (here's a fish).

But as Wojtek says in his comment, `man cp` (reading the fine manual) would be a good starting point (want to learn how to fish?).

Answer (score 4):

you can use preserve=all, then your copy will keep all attributes like owner, group and timestamp of your files. 
So, do your backup safely with the following command.

```
cp -r --preserve=all /home/my_home /media/backup/my_home
```

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` is good for copying terabytes of data. it adds resumability. And there are flags now to also copy extended attributes which is main issue in other comments.

`rsync -aHAXS --info=progress2 --partial SOURCE_DIR DESTINATION_DIR`

```
--hard-links, -H         preserve hard links
--acls, -A               preserve ACLs (implies --perms)
--xattrs, -X             preserve extended attributes
--sparse, -S             turn sequences of nulls into sparse blocks
--info=progress2         progress bar
```

source https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/rsync.

Comment: Good suggestion with **Progress** & Stats flags that `cp` does not offer e.g:
`sudo rsync -aHAXS \
--filter='-x security.selinux' \
--no-compress \
--no-inc-recursive \
--stats \
--numeric-ids \
--info=progress2 \
/media/disk/ \
/`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that I wanted to copy a large folder from one hard drive to a new one but took a while for me to consider the different partition formats.

The original was on an `ext4` formatted partition on the extraction location was an external drive formatted as `exFat`. Once I realized this I formatted the external hard drive to ext4 and it worked, but I also used the `-h` flag for de-refenrencing symlinks.

```
tar -cf myfolder.tar myfolder
cd /path/to/new/harddrive
tar -xhf myfolder.tar
```

I was using Ubuntu 22.04, for additional details.

Wanted to share this experience in case someone else finds it helpful.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is

```bsh
cp -rp /source/ /dest
```

Comment: This answer seems to be exactly like the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43608/377345) (save the for `sudo` call, which however the OP seemes to be necessary ...)

Comment: Also, you cannot preserve ownerships while copying unless you are root. Otherwise on systems with a per-user disk quota, it would allow an user to fill up other users' disk quota by making copies of their files, as a form of a local denial-of-service attack.

Answer (score -2):

well ive using Linux Zorin and my issue was trying to copy over my home folder to an external drive while my computer is booted on a iso ( bootable usb drive ) as ive messed up my sdd and it now doest bootup properly so im doing a new install, this time i hope to install windows 7 then zorin OZ successfully or just Zorin OS, im not sure if i should dual boot or do linux with virtual machine.

what i did :

install caja ( through command line or software store )

run caja as root ( i used command line and run it as ROOT )

copy and paste my files i wanted, skipped the stuff that didnt want to copy and hopefully the ones i dont care about )

DONE.

for me 20gb of my home folder is taking forever, the few minutes it has been feels like an internity right now.

Hope this helps anyone even with all my rambling here.