# IzPack Linux Keep same permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm using IzPack to pack my application contain thousand of files that should be executable.
IzPack remove the original permissions and give the unpacked files rw-rw-r--
So, there is any solution to keep the original files permissions ?
Or there's some others workaround that is can do ?

Comment: Is there any way you can invoke `bash script` while installation of IzPack.

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: IzPack come up with xml configuration files which is use for providing options for user while installation, can you call any `bash script` or `command` at the time of installation.

Comment: Yes. I can see it. But my issue here that i want IzPack to not modify the original file permission. Can it do that ?

Comment: Yes, then u can modify confiugration, and follow this instructions: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71880/unable-to-preserve-ownership-in-a-copy-but-able-with-a-move. What I want to say is just call command mentioned in link.

Comment: You mean to call rsync -o ?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29633/discussion-between-marwen-bkh-and-snoop).

Comment: Yes more examples: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43605/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-keeping-owners-and-permissions-intact