# how to do checksum on a folder in Solaris

Tags: solaris, checksum

On my Solaris machine, I sometimes use the `sum` command to verify that a file has not changed. I now want to check whether a directory's contents have changed but `sum` only runs on files.

Is there a way to run `sum` or a similar command on an entire directory?

Example `sum` on a file:

```
$ sum  file.xml
27247 11 file.xml
```

Comment: Try `tar c dir | md5sum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tar to create tarball of directory and run sum on it then.

`tar cf - <directory name> | sum -`

Comment: md5sum not relevant in solaris - tar c folder  | md5sum
md5sum: Command not found.

Comment: Does using `sum` instead of `md5sum` help?

Comment: Strange! Can you check `sum file.xml` once again

Comment: tar c folder | sum 0 0 , I can do it only on folder not on file

Comment: `sum file.xml` ?

Comment: sum file.xml
23345 11 file ( file in folder )

Comment: Find a way to create a tarball (compress) of the file /directory on solaris and run sum on it then.

Comment: @maihabunash does `tar c directory | sum -` work?

Comment: no , what its work is that -->   tar cf - <directory name> | sum

Comment: `tar` will also include [ownership, permissions and timestamps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43606/3645), so unless you care about those (normally you wouldn't) this is a bad idea.

Comment: Alternately use "digest -a md5" rather than sum.  Digest supports alternate hash mechanisms which may be useful to you.

Answer (score 6):

1) do a reference:

```
find . -type f -exec sum {} \; | sort -k3 > /my/reference.txt
```

2) do a run time check

```
find . -type f -exec sum {} \; | sort -k3 | diff /my/reference.txt -
```

where

- `sort -k3` do a sorting on file name
- `diff` part will show file changed, added or deleted.

Comment: I very much prefer this solution of the other answers as it might not always be feasible to create a tarball of the directory/directories in questions, e.g. when disk space is a limiting factor. Although the `diff` gives you richer information of the changes, if you want to have a single sum as a result/reference, you can obviously pipe on the results of the sort commands to `sum` instead of saving them to a file.

Comment: This is better if you only care about the contents of the files.

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris `tar` works differently.  So either use `gtar` from GNU or use `tar cf -` and then the solution from Miline:

```
tar cf - folder | sum
```